# how to show battery percentage on gnu screen hardstatus line

Tags: linux, battery, gnu-screen, sed

I currently have this as my hardstatus last line on gnu-screen

[image: screenshot]

the ~/.screenrc entry is as follows (just incase someone want something similar)

```
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= g}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= w}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %d/%m %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

I wish to include my notebook's battery percentage at the end. I though of using upower for that (new ideas are appreciated), by adding `$(upower -d | grep percentage | sed 'some magic stuff')` at the end, the problem is that I cannot figure out how to trim out the percentage number using sed. The output of 
`upower -d | grep percentage` is:

`[roberto@Kasama ~]$upower -d | grep percentage
    percentage:          81%
    percentage:          81%`

I tried using `sed -e 's/percentage\t//` but that does not seem to work.

EDIT:

using backtick I managed to print the percentage number by using

`$(upower -d | grep percentage | sed -n "1p" | sed -e 's/percentage:..........//')`
but I do still get some spaces, that cannot be removed by adding more dots,  before the actual number%. Any clue on how to clean those?

EDIT2:

got it almost the way I wanted it, I am now using `$(upower -d | grep percentage | sed -n "1p" | sed -e 's/^.* //')` which returns me `81%` the way I wanted it. Now I'm trying to make conditions using %? and %: to print the number in a certain color depending on how low the battery is.

Comment: I'd suggest AWK instead of sed. Something along the lines of: `upower -d|awk '$1 == "percentage:" { power=substr($2, 0, index($2, "%") - 1); if (power < 30) { color="RED"; } else if (power < 80) { color="ORANGE"; } else { color="GREEN";} printf "%d: %s\n", power, color; }'`.

Comment: pretty cool solution, but I wonder how to use those colors in screen hardstatus

Comment: The colours part was left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the `acpi` program with no argument is output the battery name,  it's status (Charging/Discharging/Full) the percentage and the estimated remaning lifetime or charging time